# Best Ways to reduce Disk IO On Linux Server

Tags: mysql, linux, apache2, disk-io

We have several linux servers, opensuse and centOS. Hosted at linode and namecheap.

All of them, at varying frequency, warn, or crash due to high Disk IO.
My question is simple. How can you reduce disk IO.

This is a general question, not specific to any particular Web App. We run many sites, none are particularly large in files or database.

Turn off logging or reduce how verbose the logs are?
Cache pages to reduce mysql lookups?

Comment: Duplicate with http://serverfault.com/questions/265901/how-to-reduce-mysql-disk-io ?

Comment: Do much possibilities what can cause a high Disk IO

Answer (score 0):

Your servers shouldn't crash due to disk IO. They stop, but don't crash, 
everything gets real slow, but crash?? Seems extreme.

What time do they crash at? 8am?
What happens if you reboot them?

Did you say webapp?

hmmm..

Dru

You could reduce IO by using smaller drives, hehe
I've got some, definitely reduced IO!!

Comment: Crash no, freeze up for years, yes. If they crashed, i'd be happier. Reboot and they'll run fine for a while.

Comment: Also,some basic web forms, login system, wordpress, various other simple sites, nothing too crazy here. All VPS, so it could be other server users too.

Comment: normally I'd be thinking backups or database replications, or both at the same time.

Comment: happens all the time, even *gasp* with backups off. Multiple servers, different software, all times of the day.